# Comparison of rows and columns of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Lets assume we have `p by n` matrix. I want to generate an output matrix, `w` (`p x p`) such as `w_ij`  represent how many times `i_th` rows number is bigger than `j_th` (can be at most `n` obviously).

My code is here, I'm looking for a faster way.

```
p <- dim(dat)[1]
n <- dim(dat)[2]
w <- matrix(0,p,p)

for(i in 1:n){
     for(j in 1:(p-1)){
         for(k in (j+1):p){
             if(dat[j,i] > dat[k,i]){                     
                   w[j,k] <- w[j,k]+1
             }else{          
                   w[k,j] <- w[k,j]+1
                   }
          }  
      }
  }
```

---

A small example

If the input data is

```
dat <- matrix(1:9, 3)
dat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9
```

the expected outcome is

```
W <- matrix(c(0,3,3,0,0,3,0,0,0),3)
W
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    0
#[2,]    3    0    0
#[3,]    3    3    0
```

Comment: I think this may benefit from a small worked example. If your data is `dat <- matrix(1:9, 3)`, what is the expected outcome?. Thanks

Comment: W=matrix(c(0,3,3,0,0,3,0,0,0),3) So we have 3 comparison times. 2nd wins 1 first 3 times and 3rd wins 1st and 2nd 3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to give a quick speed gain, without much extra work

```
newd <- t(dat)
for(i in 1:p) { 
  w[,i] <- colSums((newd - dat[i,]) > 0)
}
```

Quick comparison: wrap code in functions

```
f1 <- function(dat){
p <- dim(dat)[1]
n <- dim(dat)[2]
w <- matrix(0,p,p)
for(i in 1:n){
     for(j in 1:(p-1)){
         for(k in (j+1):p){
             if(dat[j,i] > dat[k,i]){                     
                   w[j,k] <- w[j,k]+1
             }else{          
                   w[k,j] <- w[k,j]+1
                   }
          }  
      }
  }
w
}

f2 <- function(dat){
p <- dim(dat)[1]
w <- matrix(0,p,p)
newd <- t(dat)
for(i in 1:p) { 
  w[,i] <- colSums((newd - dat[i,]) > 0)
} ; w}
```

Generate slightly larger data

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(1e4), 100)
```

Compare

```
all.equal(f1(dat), f2(dat))
```

Benchmark

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(dat), f2(dat), times=10)
#    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval  cld
# f1(dat) 1586.10589 1594.40701 1619.03102 1616.14899 1635.05695 1688.08589    10  b
# f2(dat)   22.56083   23.13493   23.98392   23.34228   24.39766   28.29201    10  a
```

Of course, depending on the size of your matrix it may be worth writing your loops in c++/Rcpp for larger speed gains

Comment: There might be (?) some improvements, I guess, (1) if you save `t(dat)` once and before looping and, (2) if you minimize comparisons to between `dat[i, ]`and `dat[(i + 1):nrow(dat), ]` (or something similar) to avoid comparing all pairs twice; that could be -e.g.- the `lower.tri` of "w" and fill the `upper.tri` with something like `ncol(dat) - lower.tri` (for example, if row1 is in 3 columns > than row 6, then 6 will be > than 1 in `ncol(dat) - 3` columns).

Comment: Hi Alexis. Ugh, yup, moving the transpose outside will increase speed . Yes, i thought of just computing the lower matrix, but wa combination of being a bit lazy (not wanting to think of non-square matrix) and, more complicated code. Ill update the `t`. Thanks